# How to derive the cdf of given function

Tags: statistics, central-limit-theorem

Let
$$Y = \frac{X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_{100}}{100}$$

I understand that the Central Limit Theorem says you can approximate Y.

But by what random variable?

And how can I write the cumulative distribution function of this random variable?

I am confused on how to derive the CDF. Do I need to find the PDF first?

Comment: Central limit theorem approximates things as a normal random variable.

Comment: Are the $X_i$´s identically and independently distributed  ?

Comment: yes. they are iid

Comment: The CLT does not, let me repeat, **does not**, describe such sums. Assuming that $(Y_n)$ is i.i.d. and integrable, the best approximation of $$\frac{Y_1+\cdots+Y_n}n$$ when $n$ is large, is $$E(Y_1)$$ Hence, considering the CDFs $$F_n(y)=P(n^{-1}(Y_1+\cdots+Y_n)\leqslant y)$$ one has $F_n(y)\to0$ for every $y<E(Y_1)$ and $F_n(y)\to1$ for every $y>E(Y_1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CLT claims that the sum of a large number of $i.i.d.$ random variables are approximately normal distributed. One thumb of rule is that large number is more than $30$.

Let´s say $Y=\sum_{i=1}^{100} X_i$. Then $Y$ is approximately distributed as $Y\sim\mathcal N(100\cdot \mu_x, 100\cdot \sigma_x^2)$

$\mu_x is $the identical expected value for every $X_i$

$\sigma_x$ is the identical standard deviation for every $X_i$

Therefore $P(Y\leq y)\approx \Phi\left( \frac{y-100\cdot \mu_x}{\sqrt{100\cdot \sigma_x^2}} \right)$

where $\Phi\left( z \right)$ is the cdf of the standard normal distribution.

---

Now we calculate the expected value and the variance of $\frac1{100}Y=\overline Y$

- $\mathbb E\left(\frac1{100}Y\right)=\frac1{100}\mathbb
     E\left(Y\right)$
- $Var\left(\frac1{100}Y\right)=\left(\frac1{100}\right)^2Var\left(Y\right)$

Thus $\frac1{100} Y=\overline Y$ is approximately distributed as $\overline Y\sim \mathcal N( \mu_x, \frac1{100}\sigma_x^2)$.

Finally we have

$$P(\overline Y\leq y)\approx \Phi\left( \frac{y- \mu_x}{\sqrt{\frac1{100}\cdot \sigma_x^2}} \right)=\Phi\left( \frac{y- \mu_x}{\frac1{10}\cdot \sigma_x} \right)$$